# Call an external function from inside function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I try to extend jQuery, but when I call myTest this will return this.myTest.test() is undefined...

can someone tell me why...

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myTest=function() {

        var x=function() {
            this.myTest.test();

            var b = function() {
                this.myTest.coba();
            }
        }

        x();

        return this.each(function(){
        });
    };

    $.fn.myTest.test = function(){
        alert('test'); 
    };

    $.fn.myTest.coba = function(){
        alert('coba'); 
    };

    $.fn.myTest.iseng = function(){
        alert('iseng'); 
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `this.myTest.test();` from within the nested function `x`. Thus `this` won't point to the `$.fn.myTest` object.

You will run into the same problem with `this.myTest.coba();` in function `b`.

To solve that you have to store the context of the `$.fn.myTest` object beforehand to access it:

```
$.fn.myTest=function() {

    var self = this;
    var x=function() {
        self.myTest.test();

        var b = function() {
            self.myTest.coba();
        }
    }

    x();

    return this.each(function(){
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The this inside the x() function is not the jQuery object, but is the `window`, as far as I know. Here's what you need...

```
$.fn.myTest = function() {
    var that = this;
    var x=function() {
        that.myTest.test();

        var b = function() {
            that.myTest.coba();
        }
    }

    x();

    return this.each(function(){
    });
};
```